# I'm stuck in calculating $_2F_1(1,1;\tfrac12;\tfrac12)$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

By using $(71)$ and $(70)$ identities of Mathworld's [hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) page,
$${_2}F{_1}(1,1;\tfrac12;\tfrac12)\stackrel{(71)}{=}2\,{_2}F{_1}(1,-\tfrac12;\tfrac12;-1)\stackrel{(70)}{=}2\left(\tfrac{\sqrt\pi}2\tfrac{\Gamma(\tfrac12)}{\Gamma(1)}+1\right)=\pi+2.$$
But, WolframAlpha calculates it as $\tfrac{\pi}2+2.$ Where is my mistake?

I also wonder whether there is an Euler-type integral that can be used to calculate ${_2}F{_1}(1,1;\tfrac12;\tfrac12)$.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: After some experimentation (i.e., having Mathematica simplify some simple cases) it seems like the error is on Mathworld's end: Eq. 70 should be $${_2}F_1(1,-a;a,-1)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1/2)}+1.$$ That is, (70) should have $\Gamma(a+1)=a~\Gamma (a)$ not $\Gamma(a)$. I'll see if I can prove this or track down a source which has the latter version.

Comment: Use [$(15.4.27)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E27) with $a=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In these cases, I usually run a numerical simulation. Numerical computations run on an entirely different route than the analytical ones. Here, the contested values differ by $\sim 1.57$, so you will clearly see which one is closer to the numerical result and rule out the wrong one.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to obtain the identity ${_2}F{_1}(1,1;\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}+2 $ directly from Euler's integral representation.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you very much. But I accepted an answer before you posted your answer and s/he has no gold. I can't change.

Comment: That's okay.  I just wanted to make sure you were aware that I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only *real* Euler-type integral (barring complex contour integrals that *look like* Euler-type integrals in their integrands) is
\begin{align}
{_2}F{_1}(1,1;\frac{1}{2}; -1) = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-2t} {_1}F{_1}(1,\frac{1}{2}, t) \,dt,
\end{align}

(NIST Handbook 2010, eq. 13.10.3)

It is easily verifiable that

$${_1}F{_1}(1,\frac{1}{2}, t) = 1 + e^t \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{t}   \;\text{erf}(\sqrt{t})$$

in which $\text{erf}$ is the error function
(hint: combine NIST Handbook 2010, eq. 13.6.5 and 13.6.7 p. 332 with $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ and integrate using 13.3.15; or expand series).

Hence:

\begin{align}
{_2}F{_1}(1,1;\frac{1}{2}; -1) = 1+ 2 \sqrt{\pi} \; \mathscr{L}(\sqrt{t} \text{ erf}(\sqrt{t}); 1)
\end{align}

The Laplace transform  $\mathscr{L}(\sqrt{t} \text{ erf}(\sqrt{t}); p)$ is tabulated (for example, Prudnikov et al. Vol. 4, eq. 8 p. 172):

$$\mathscr{L}(\sqrt{t} \text{ erf}(\sqrt{t}); p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi p^3}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{p}}{p+1} + \arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}})\right)$$
whence

\begin{align}
{_2}F{_1}(1,1;\frac{1}{2}; -1) &= 1+ 2 \sqrt{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \arctan(1)\right) \\
&= 2 + 2 \arctan(1) \\
&= 2 + \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

It follows that Mathworld has a mistake in its equation $(70)$ as commented by Semiclassical.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: The identity $${_2}F{_1}(1,1;\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}+2$$ can actually be obtained directly from [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).  I show this in the second part of my answer.

---

As **Semiclassical** pointed out in the comments, equation (70) should be $${_2}F_1(1,-a;a;-1)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2})}+1. $$

We can use [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type) to prove that this indentity holds for $a>0$.

First assume that $a>1$.

Using Euler's integral representation, we have $$ \begin{align} {_2}F_1(1,-a;a;-1) &= {_2}F_1(-a,1;a;-1) \\ &= \frac{1}{B(1,a-1)}  \int_{0}^{1} x^{1-1} (1-x)^{a-2}(1+x)^a \, \mathrm dx \\&= (a-1) \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-x)^{a-2}(1+x)^{a} \, \mathrm dx. \end{align}$$

Then integrating by parts, we have

$$ \begin{align} {_2}F_1(1,-a;a;-1) &= -  (1+x)^{a}(1-x)^{a-1} \bigg|_{0}^{1} + a\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{a-1}(1+x)^{a-1} \, \mathrm dx  \\ &= 1 +a \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^{2})^{a-1} \, \mathrm dx. \end{align}$$

We now have an integral representation for ${_2}F_1(1,-a;a;-1) $ that converges for $a>0$.

Evaluating the integral, we get $$ \begin{align} {_2}F_1(1,-a;a;-1) &= 1 + \frac{a}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (1-u)^{a-1} u^{-1/2} \, \mathrm du \\ &= 1+ \frac{a}{2} \, B\left(a, \tfrac{1}{2}\right) \\ &= 1 + \frac{a}{2} \frac{\Gamma(a) \sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma \left(a+ \frac{1}{2} \right)} \\ &= 1 + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(a+1) }{\Gamma \left(a+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}. \end{align}$$

---

We can also obtain the identity $${_2}F{_1}(1,1;\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}+2 $$ directly from Euler's integral representation.

First assume that $a>1$.

Then an integral representation for ${_2}F_{1} \left(1,1;a,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ is $$ \begin{align} {_2}F_{1} \left(1,1;a,\tfrac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{1}{B(1,a-1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1-1} (1-x)^{a-2} \left(1- \frac{x}{2} \right)^{-1} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= 2 (a-1) \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^{a-2}}{2-x} \, \mathrm dx. \end{align}$$

Integrating by parts, we have $$ \begin{align} {_2}F_{1} \left(1,1;a,\tfrac{1}{2}\right) &= -2 \, \frac{(1-x)^{a-1}}{2-x} \bigg|_{0}^{1} + 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x)^{a-1}}{(2-x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &=1 + 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x)^{a-1}}{(2-x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \end{align}$$

We now have an integral representation for ${_2}F_{1} \left(1,1;a,\tfrac{1}{2}\right) $ that converges for $a>0$.

At $a= \frac{1}{2}$, we have

$$ \begin{align} {_2}F_{1} \left(1,1;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\right) &= 1 + 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x)^{-1/2}}{(2-x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= 1+ 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{-1/2}}{(1+u)^{2}} \, \mathrm du  \\ &= 1 + 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\left(\tan^{2}(v)\right)^{-1/2}}{\left(1+\tan^{2}(v)\right)^{2}} \, 2 \tan(v) \sec^{2}(v) \, \mathrm dv \\ &=1 + 4 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \cos^{2}(v) \, \mathrm dv \\ &=  2+ \frac{\pi}{2}. \end{align}$$